# Changing Font style in qtquickcontrols2.conf file in Qt 5.9.1

Tags: qt, fonts, styles, default, qtquickcontrols2

I've been experimenting with styles in Qt. Is there any way to change more things than just Theme, Accent, Foregroud and Background using the qtquickcontrols2.conf file?

I have looked at:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-configuration.html
and they say that IT IS possible to configure the font, however, if I try to do this I see NO change in ANY of the properties.

BTW, I only have a QML file with a button in it. I want to know if using qtquickcontrols2.conf file is possible to change font styles.

An example of what the .conf file would look like would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no support for configuring fonts in `:/qtquickcontrols2.conf` in Qt 5.9. Fonts were made configurable in `:/qtquickcontrols2.conf` starting with Qt 5.10. The documentation you have linked to is for Qt 5.10, and contains an example:

```
[Default]
Font\Family=Open Sans
Font\PixelSize=20

[Material\Font]
Family=Open Sans
PixelSize=20
```

If you run this with Qt 5.10.0 or later, you get the desired fonts.

The same documentation lists all available font attributes that you can specify: `Family`, `PointSize`, `PixelSize`, `StyleHint`, `Weight`, and `Style`. What you want is the last one, but as said, you need Qt 5.10 if you want to configure the fonts in `:/qtquickcontrols2.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that font changes that are set for Controls 2 propagate to their children as well.

So you can simply put a `Page` as your root element in `main.qml` and then you can specify every font option you have access to from QML, plus also set the default font to be a custom font through a `FontLoader`, and those will be effectively applied to all controls unless explicitly changed.

That's a whole lot more functionality than what you can set from the `conf` file.